# The "branch-depth" parameter and its use in FPT algorithms

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, fixed-parameter-tractable

Let $P=(v_1,\dots,v_q)$ be an induced path in the undirected graph $G(V,E)$. In [1], the authors define the *branch depth* of $P$ to be $b(P)=|N_G[\{v_1,\dots,v_{q-1}\}]|-1$. Further, in [1] it is shown that for graphs where $b(P)$ is bounded (i.e., $b(P)<t$ for all induced paths $P$), then the 2-disjoint connected subgraphs problem can be decided in time $O^*(3^{\frac{t}{3}})$.

While I searched, I could not find any other uses of this parameter, and was wondering whether it has perhaps different names. For example, it is clear that $P_k$-free graphs with bounded degree also have bounded branch-depth. Are there other papers that use this parameter, or a parameter similar to it ?

[1] "Connecting Terminals and 2-Disjoint Connected Subgraphs" by Jan Arne Telle and Yngve Villanger